# Java, how to make this into a generic method?

Tags: java, generics, methods

How would I refactor the code below into 1 generic method?
(background info, it is used to get values from a Json string used with GSON library)

```
ArrayList<Map<Object, Object>> theme = new ArrayList<Map<Object, Object>>();
for (int i = 0; i < obj.getThemeList().size(); i = i + 1) {
    if(Boolean.parseBoolean(obj.getThemeList().get(i).getChecked())){
        Map<Object,Object> map = new HashMap<Object,Object>();
        map.put("id", obj.getThemeList().get(i).getId());
        map.put("name", obj.getThemeList().get(i).getName());
        theme.add(map);
    }
}
```

---

```
ArrayList<Map<Object, Object>> tag = new ArrayList<Map<Object, Object>>();
for (int i = 0; i < obj.getTagList().size(); i = i + 1) {
    if(Boolean.parseBoolean(obj.getTagList().get(i).getChecked())){
        Map<Object,Object> map = new HashMap<Object,Object>();
        map.put("id", obj.getTagList().get(i).getId());
        map.put("name", obj.getTagList().get(i).getName());
        tag.add(map);
    }
}
```

Comment: What types do `getTagList` and `getThemeList` return?

Comment: What does it have to do with `generics`?

Answer (score 4):

Basically, just make it a single method that accepts the `getThemeList()` or `getTagList()`, no?  It looks like that's the only difference between them...

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean "how can I refactor this to reuse code", because generics does not apply here as much as refactoring does.

Firstly, read up on the [foreach syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) -  your for loop is really ugly.

You haven't given much to go on, but try this:

```
public interface HasIdNameAndChecked {
    String getChecked();
    String getId();
    String getName();
}

public static List<Map<String, String>> extractList(List<? extends HasIdNameAndChecked> items) {
    List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    for (HasIdNameAndChecked item : items) {
        if (Boolean.parseBoolean(item.getChecked())){
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("id", item.getId());
            map.put("name", item.getName());
            list.add(map);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Then have your `Theme` and `Tag` classes implement `HasIdNameAndChecked`, and call it like this:

```
List<Map<String, String>> list1 = extractThemeList(obj.getThemeList());
List<Map<String, String>> list2 = extractThemeList(obj.getTagList());
```

Disclaimer: I typed this in without an IDE, so there could be a couple of typos.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's do it in following order:

1. **Identify what varies.** themeList and tagList.
2. **Identify common properties and behaviour.** getChecked(), getId(), getName().
3. **Apply generalization for what varies.** Define a common interface for what varies: abstract class, interface, behaviour, etc.
4. **Update your solution to generalized solution.**